# How to execute function inside the table in Lua?

Tags: lua

i have a table with funcion calls, how can i run them from the table?  my table is looks like this

```
    local checkTable = 
    {
        ["Storable"] = 
        {
            InventoryManager.canAddToPlayerInventory,
            InventoryManager.addToPlayerInventory
        }
    }
```

Comment: here [ "Storable"] will contain the returns of your functions, but not the functions

Comment: i fixed that part but still not sure how can i execute the functions

Comment: `checkTable["Storable"][1](...) ` or `checkTable.Storable[1](...) ` for `InventoryManager.canAddToPlayerInventory`